# my btn's onclick code make a "ArgumentException" wrong

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i try to make a keyboard with lot of btn, and i got "ArgumentException: Object of type 'UnityEngine.Object' cannot be converted to type 'UnityEngine.GameObject'." as the result...

heres my code, can somebody tell the newbie where went wrong...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class a : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        List<string> btns = new List<string>();
        btns.Add("aa"); // aa is the btn name.
        foreach (var item in btns)
        {
            GameObject bo = GameObject.Find(item);
            Button btn = bo.GetComponent<Button>();
            btn.onClick.AddListener(delegate(){
                this.OnClick(bo);
            });
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
    
    }

    public void OnClick(GameObject sender)
    {
        Debug.Log("ah");
    }
}
```

i want to press a btn and it'll type the btn's alphebat in a string array.
but when it went wrong i have tried to use Debug.Log() to see where the bug is...

Comment: Can you add the stack trace of the `ArgumentException` to your question please?

Comment: Can you please read about [how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541) and apply what you learn to improve your question post? You can also read [ask] for further guidance.